# Asset:Precompile too verbose

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline

I am new to JRuby and Rails. When I precompile my assets it fills my logs with junk that I am not interested in.

(in /srv/test/releases/cba9797f510b211ff3568c9bb800ee7a7366c319)
mkdir -p /srv/test/releases/cba9797f510b211ff3568c9bb800ee7a7366c319/public/assets
mkdir -p /srv/test/releases/cba9797f510b211ff3568c9bb800ee7a7366c319/public/assets/controllers
mkdir -p /srv/test/releases/cba9797f510b211ff3568c9bb800ee7a7366c319/public/assets/controllers
mkdir -p /srv/test/releases/cba9797f510b211ff3568c9bb800ee7a7366c319/public/assets/controllers
mkdir -p /srv/test/releases/cba9797f510b211ff3568c9bb800ee7a7366c319/public/assets/controllers
mkdir -p /srv/test/releases/cba9797f510b211ff3568c9bb800ee7a7366c319/public/assets/controllers
mkdir -p /srv/test/releases/cba9797f510b211ff3568c9bb800ee7a7366c319/public/assets/controllers

I have tried --quiet, i have turned logging off.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Still seems to be happening, anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever find a fix? It's annoying the heck out of me too.

Comment: When executing in a shell, you can redirect the output to a file. E.g. for bash `./your/command > /dev/null` or `./your/command 2> /dev/null` for stderr.

Answer (score 7):

There are two main output suppressor options that you might want to consider.

**Do not log messages to standard output.**

```
-q, --quiet
```

**Also suppresses the 'in directory' announcement.**

```
-s, --silent
```

Silent is probably the option you were looking for. You can view all the options for most rake tasks by adding the --help option. For example:

```
rake assets:precompile --help
```

Hope this helps. For more info on precompiling assets see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8492829/images-in-rails-3-1-moving-to-production/).