# Images in rails 3.1 - moving to production

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

My articles have images.  I put the images in app/assests/images and store their location in a field in the database.

Then I can display them in by using:

```
<%= image_tag(@article.image) %>
```

But when I move to the production server, none of my images show up!  The server's looking for assets/blank-d5dd6e3683b4753dfde3c70cf61f99b6.png rather than blank.png and it isn't available.

How do I sort this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem I ran into when Rails 3.1 was released.

### Normal assets

If your assets are manually placed by you then all you have to do is run:

```
rake assets:precompile
```

This will precompile your assets into `public/assets`.

It's best to precompile on your **production server** so you don't have unessential files on your development server.

### Uploaded assets

If you are uploading images using something like [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip), then don't use the asset folder.

You need put your images in the public folder. In your case probably `public/assets/articles`

### Further Info

- RailsGuides - [Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)